# Kriging Interpolation in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, interpolation, kriging, geostatistical-analyst

I want to interpolate one field of the shapefile named '**Interpolation**' by Kriging method. But want to change the processing environment to the extent of another file namely '**Polygon**'.
[image]

I tried '**Geostatistical Analyst**' in ArcMap 10.5 but found the result as shown in the image attached which is limited to the extent of the layer **Interpolation**. I am unable to change the processing environment.

[image]

How do I change the processing environment for Geostatistical Analyst?

Comment: You can set the Mask or Processing Extent in the Environment Settings using the button on the tool. Mask is under Raster Analysis and will clip the output raster to fit the shape of the boundary. @engingem has a link for processing extent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able change it on geostatistical layer properties dialog. Here is the documentation link. It's for 10.6 but probably it is same.

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/extensions/geostatistical-analyst/changing-the-extent-of-a-geostatistical-layer.htm

Comment: Thanks @engingem. How do I clip Geostastical Layer to my area of interest  **'Polygon'**  ?

Comment: Geostastical Layer is a dynamic representation and could be exported to raster or vector by right click layer and selecting Data > Export to Raster or Data > Export to Vector. Depending your workflow Clip Raster or Clip function will handle clipping of your area of interest.